# Method synchronization issue. Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm trying to comprehend multithreading in Java and I encountered the following issue:
I created 20 threads and each thread performs a simple operation of incrementing and getting some value. Please find code excerpt below:

```
public class MyClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i ++) {
     new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " == " + MyClass1.incAndGet());
     }).start();
  }

}

private static class MyClass1 {

  static private int s;

  private static synchronized int incAndGet(){
     return s ++;
  }

 }
}
```

Here accsess to incAndGet method is synchronized, so that no thread can find state of s variable in an incossistent thread. What I cannot understand is why output is the following:

```
Thread-0 == 2
Thread-11 == 10
Thread-14 == 12
Thread-15 == 9
Thread-18 == 14
Thread-13 == 8
....
```

Shouldn't it be like:

```
Thread-0 == 0
Thread-11 == 11
Thread-14 == 14
Thread-15 == 15
Thread-18 == 18
Thread-13 == 13
....
```

If I misunderstood the concept of synchronization, can you please provide examples of good and bad synchronization. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your threads job there are conventionally two basic oprations: `incAndGet()` and `System.out.println()`. The order of this operations also isn't sequential: such `Thread-13` can do `incAndGet`, then `Thread-18` will do `incAndGet` and then `Thread-18` will do `System.out.println()` earlier then `Thread-13`. So, if you want sequentinal printout you should synchonize `incAndGet` with `println`:

```
  synchronized (MyClass.class) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " == " + MyClass1.incAndGet());
                }
```

Comment: That won't prevent the threads from printing in an order that is different from the order in which they were started.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that Thread will be executing in a Sequential way.
on different run it will show you different output.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers don't match because the scheduler is running the threads in a different order to the order they were created. The thread name is decided at creation time, while the number `s` is computed when the thread actually runs.